# High Memory Usage Issue in Qt Remote Object

Tags: c++, qt, qtremoteobjects

I have recently been learning how to use Qt Remote Objects and have written a small program based on the official documentation: a client-server architecture instant messaging application.

The code is as follows：
server Header File:

```
#ifndef SIMPLESWITCH_H
#define SIMPLESWITCH_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include "rep_simpleswitch_source.h"

class SimpleSwitch : public SimpleSwitchSimpleSource
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   SimpleSwitch(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~SimpleSwitch();

    void byteArrayTest(char nChar);

public Q_SLOTS:
   void timeout_slot();

private:
   QTimer* stateChangeTimer;
};

#endif // SIMPLESWITCH_H
```

server Source File:

```
#include "simpleswitch.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QSignalSpy>

SimpleSwitch::SimpleSwitch(QObject* parent) : SimpleSwitchSimpleSource(parent)
{
    stateChangeTimer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(stateChangeTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SimpleSwitch::timeout_slot);
    stateChangeTimer->start(2000);
}

SimpleSwitch::~SimpleSwitch()
{
    stateChangeTimer->stop();
}

void SimpleSwitch::timeout_slot()
{
    static int nCount = 1;
    if(nCount == 5)
    {
        qDebug() << "nCount = "<< nCount;
        byteArrayTest(1);
    }
    if (nCount == 10)
    {
        qDebug() << "nCount = " << nCount;
        QByteArray byteArray;
        byteArray.append(1);

        setByteArray(byteArray);
        //③ Memory has become 130MB

        stateChangeTimer->stop();
    }
    ++nCount;
}

void SimpleSwitch::byteArrayTest(char nChar)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;


    for(int index = 0; index < 65535 * 1000; ++index)
    {
        byteArray.append(nChar+index);
    }
    //① Allocated 63MB of memory
    // 65535 * 1000 / 1024 / 1024 = 63M

    
    setByteArray(byteArray);
    //② The memory has increased to 302MB


    //after ② Memory has returned to 194MB
}
```

client:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include "rep_simpleswitch_replica.h"

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client(QSharedPointer<SimpleSwitchReplica> ptr)
            : QObject(nullptr), reptr(ptr)
    {
        QObject::connect(reptr.data(), &SimpleSwitchReplica::byteArrayChanged, this, &Client::onByteArrayChanged);
    }

    ~Client() { }

public Q_SLOTS:
    void onByteArrayChanged(QByteArray byteArray)
    {
        qDebug() << "onByteArrayChanged";
    }

private:
    QSharedPointer<SimpleSwitchReplica> reptr;
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

rep file:

```
class SimpleSwitch
{
    PROP(QByteArray byteArray);
};
```

The client responds to the byteArrayChanged signal with the onByteArrayChanged function, which does nothing and is an empty function.

The memory changes are shown in the following figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pnny.png)

Why is the memory changing like this?
Why is so much memory needed?
How can we bring down the memory usage?

Comment: Does adding a call to `bytearray.reserve(65535 * 1000);` to the top of `SimpleSwitch::byteArrayTest()` help?  By telling the `QByteArray` up-front how much data you plan to put into it, you can help it avoid needlessly allocating more RAM than it will actually need to use.  (see:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html#reserve )

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I changed the code like this:  QByteArray byteArray;
    byteArray.reserve(65535 * 1000);

    for(int index = 0; index < 65535 * 1000; ++index)
    {
        byteArray.append(nChar+index);
    }
The memory usage is the same as the code above.

Comment: It's not caused by QByteArray. The memory changes process: 2M-66M-302M-194M-130M. The increase from 2MB to 66MB is caused by QByteArray. After debugging, the increase from 66MB to 302MB is caused by setByteArray(byteArray);

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code on Qt 6.2.4 and it worked fine. It seems like a bug in Qt 5.15.I can't migrate the project to Qt 6 (Qt 6 doesn't support Windows 7).I'm wondering if it's possible to compile the Remote Objects module of Qt 6 separately and then use it in Qt 5?Or maybe there's a better idea？

Comment: You could run `diff` on the relevant `.cpp` files in the Qt5 and Qt6 codebases and see what has changed between the buggy version and the non-buggy version; if you're lucky, you'll see the code where they fixed this bug and you could then apply that same fix to the Qt5 version you use.

Comment: This seems a bit difficult.I compared it, and there were quite a few changes in the code.I compiled all versions of the Qt Remote Object module between Qt 5.15 and Qt 6 into dynamic libraries and gave it a try. They all have the same issue.I can't find a better solution for now.